# getting wrong value when using volatile keyword in java

Tags: java

I have doubt in the behaviour of volatile keyword.

```
public class TestClassI extends Thread {

    private volatile int i=5;
    boolean flag;
    public TestClassI( boolean flag) {
        this.i=i;
        this.flag=flag;
    }   
    public void run()
    {
        if(flag)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i=10;
        }
    }
}
```

and in main class using as

```
public class TestMain {

    public static volatile int i=5;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {

        TestClassI test= new TestClassI( true);
        test.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        TestClassI test2=new TestClassI( false);        
        test2.start();
    }
}
```

I expected the value will be like
5
5
5
5
10
10
10
10.
But it is keep on giving 5. But asper nature of volatile value of i should be stored and retrieved from main memory each time. Please explain is there anything wrong in this code?

Comment: You change i to 10 or prints the unchanged value out, but you never do both.

Answer (score 3):

You have two instances of `TestClassI`. They each have their own version of `i` (because it is an instance field). They don't interfere at all with eachother.

The static `TestMain.i` is not used in the program at all. There is no shared state.

Comment: Without volatile also we can have same result if we use static. So what makes difference? please explain..

Answer (score 0):

When the object is instantiated with a false flag, the run method initializes `i` to 10, and returns. `i` is never printed:

```
if (flag) {
    // irrelevant
}
else {
    i = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't set `i=10`in your loop, so it will be set as the only action in your thread, but never printed...

Answer (score -2):

`volatile` variables have no effect in this case because the variable is an `int`. `long` and `double` variables are affected by `volatile`, they are loaded and stored in one operation that can't be interrupted rather than two, one for each word. So the `volatile` variables have no effect.

What is happening that produces the unusual output is that the `i` is not shared among your threads. If you look, there is a separate `i` for each thread, although there is a static `i` in the main class. FYI, the `i` in the main class is left unnoticed by the threads, who don't notice it at all. If you'd like it to work, one simple modification will suffice: make the `i` variable in the thread static. Not in the main class, in the thread.

Comment: Volatile very much has effects on ints just like on any other variable. Volatile has the program write the value back into main memory every time is is modified, as well as getting it from there every time when accessing, instead of looking at the cache first. Good for multi-threaded environments!

Comment: I don't believe in volatile variables. I hear that they spread disease through all code that comes near them.